# web view in tab page android application

Tags: android

i wanna ask this simple question
i have this java class for one of my tabs in application:-

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Tab3 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public static Tab3 newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        Tab3 fragment = new Tab3();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3,container,false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

and i want to add this web view code in the above code:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
    }
}
```

how can i mix between two code because i try to much and i'm failed cuz i'm still too begginers in android
please help me
thank you

also if i wanna add this code:-

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

    private ToggleButton toggleButton1, toggleButton2;
    private Button btnDisplay;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        toggleButton1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
        toggleButton2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
        btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);

        btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
                result.append("toggleButton1 : ").append(
                        toggleButton1.getText());
                result.append("\ntoggleButton2 : ").append(
                        toggleButton2.getText());

                Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this, result.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });

    }
}
```

how can i mix between tab code and this last code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
public class Tab3 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public static Tab3 newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        Tab3 fragment = new Tab3();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3,container,false);
       WebView mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
        return v;
    } }
```

> add webview in XML of  R.layout.tab3

Comment: amazing it's work with me thaaanks
can i ask another question ?

Comment: if its worked for you please accept and upvote the answer.and ask your next question . i will try to help

Comment: let me know what is your next question

Comment: can you see the above question again i edit it with my next question really thank you and sorry for my stupid start in android -_-

Comment: copy your  addListenerOnButton(); inside oncreate view and write your all code in the Tab3..  and pass view to  addListenerOnButton(v);  and take the handle  like  v.findviewByid(R.id.id);

Comment: @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        addListenerOnButton(v);
    }
    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3, container, false);
        
        toggleButton1 = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
        toggleButton2 = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
        btnDisplay = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);
        return v;
        btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Comment: if you can understand code did you mean like this ?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this out**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3,container,false);
 mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
    return v;
}
```